# Why this program doesn't output anything

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class oboroten3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 2;
    int b = 1000000;
    while (b > 2) {
        double d = Math.sqrt(b);
        long p = Math.round(d);
        int c = b % 10;
        if ((c == 1) || (c == 3) || (c == 7) || (c == 9)) {
            while ((i < p) && (b % i != 0)) {
                if (i == b - 1) {
                    System.out.print(b + ",");
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        i = 2;
        b++;
    }

}
}
```

Nothing happens when I run the program, it is ment to find prime numbers, it was working before I added the part that takes the root of b

Comment: `b` is ***ALWAYS*** bigger than 2

Comment: Use a debugger to first find the source of your bug. Best to do this *before* posting a question here.

Comment: Eclpise shows me no errors, and b is ment to be like that, it shouldn't stop the program from running

Comment: I've sure I've seen this recently.

Comment: @Tom Attach a debugger in Eclipse. If you don't know what that means, then please Google that term. It will be a monumental step forward for you as a developer and I can't recommend it enough. EDIT: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-stepping.htm

Comment: Ah yes [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049494/why-this-program-doesnt-output-anything).

Comment: @Kon thank you for the link, should I download some plug in debugger or to use the build in ecplise ?

Comment: @Tom The Eclipse built-in debugger is perfect for what you need to do. Just enter debug mode, and walk through the code line by line. You will be able to see the values of all variables *live* as the code executes each line. It'll help you grow and understand your code better

Answer (score 0):

For starters you do

```
while (b > 2)
```

when b is already set to 1000000, and then you increase b on every loop

So this is going to run infinitely without stopping. That's probably the first thing you should fix.

Comment: I made the program like that so I can see how fast it runs, how much it loads my CPU... so on but it should not stop it from running

Comment: Add a system out print below ever "if", that way you will be able to see if you ever get into the loop. Another problem I noticed is that i is always going to increase, so if you run enough loops "i" might be bigger than "p" to start with, and you will never go into your while loop. Since there is nothing syntactically wrong with your code (in terms of throwing an error) I can only conclude your math is off, and your "if" conditions are never satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this condition stops the control from entering into inner `while` loop and hence, it does not print anything:

`(i < p)`

Before the outer `while`, i is initialised to 2 and b is initialised to 1000000.  Now, your `if` condition (inside the inner `while`) checks if `i` is equal to `b - 1`, this will never be possible if `i` is less than `p`. So, if you remove `(i < p)` condition, it will work fine. Your while loop would be:

`while (b % i != 0) {`